# Как тестировать payload в post запросах redux-saga

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, redux, testng, redux-saga

Недавно я начал изучать тесты для react-saga и нигде не увидел как делать запросы fetch с каким то payload

Есть вот такой воркер

```
 try {
        yield put({type: "SET_CURRENT_COMPETITION_LOADING", payload: true});

        const response: Response =  yield call(getCompetitionsData.getCompetitionById, action.payload);  // Этот payload (id: number)

        const data: ICompetitions | IApiRequestError  = yield call([response, response.json]);

        if("error" in data || "errorCode" in data) {
            throw new Error(`Произошла ошибка ${data.error ? data.error : data.errorCode}: ${data.message}`);
        }

        yield put({type: "SET_CURRENT_COMPETITION", payload: data});
        yield put({type: "SET_CURRENT_COMPETITION_LOADING", payload: false});
   
    } catch (error: any) {
        yield put({type: "SET_CURRENT_COMPETITION_ERROR", payload: error.message});
        yield put({type: "SET_CURRENT_COMPETITION_LOADING", payload: false});
    }
```

сам тест:

```
it("get currnet competition succes", () => {
        
   const generator = getCurrentCompetition();

   expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(put({type: "SET_CURRENT_COMPETITION_LOADING", payload: true}));

        const payload = 1;

   expect(generator.next(payload).value).toEqual(call(getCompetitionsData.getCompetitionById,Что передавать сюда??))

    })
```

call возвращает

```
"action": Object {
    +       "payload": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'payload')",
    +       "type": "SET_CURRENT_COMPETITION_ERROR",
          },
```

Как правильно протестировать post запрос с payload??

Answer (score -1):

В самой документации достотчно подробно описано как тестировать различные кейсы в Redux-Saga. Можете ознакомьтся [здесь](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing/)

Comment: Исчерпывающий ответ, спасибо!

Comment: @user469485 если вам помог мой овтет, то прошу отметье мой ответ как правильный! Буду вам очень признателен!

Comment: Теперь я понял, почему вы дали такой ответ